# no data for sys.resource_stats

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I tried to run the query on Azure database's usage information and it gave me blank, running on Master database. Azure portal shows me all the data.

The query is

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.resource_stats 
WHERE database_name = 'NameOfDatabase'
```

Second query is

```
SELECT start_time, end_time,    
(SELECT Max(v)    
FROM (VALUES (avg_cpu_percent), (avg_physical_data_read_percent),(avg_log_write_percent)) AS value(v)) AS [avg_DTU_percent]  
FROM sys.resource_stats 
WHERE database_name = '<your db name>' 
ORDER BY end_time DESC;
```

The second query is taking from the following site

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269979.aspx

It works for me in the past, I have some program which depend on the above query to get the data. Can somebody help me?

There is a bug or something.

[image: Image after querying the database]

Comment: yes, I properly fill out the database name part. I run this query before and it work. All of the sudden the query is not working for me. It is probably has to do with Microsoft changing their Azure database or something. The database part is "WHERE database_name = 'WholeSaleData'

Comment: Did you upgraded your server recently to V12? Are you seeing any data if provided without where clause?

Comment: No I did not upgrade but it shows V12 on my portal. I will do some investigation. It is strange. The query 1 should work on both V11 and V12

Comment: just trying to isolate the problem, can you run the following query by connecting to the database: select @@version; sp_helptext('sys.resource_Stats')

Comment: It worked now. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It might really be a typo, but did you properly fill out the `<your db name>` part?